# How do you use a typedef struct for a FIFO?

Tags: c, struct, typedef, fifo

I just started programming in C for school. I am being asked to do a program that uses a FIFO struct to resolve math problems. I got the folowing code on the internet for a FIFO, I just don't know how to use it. I tried a lot of things and I can't find anything useful on the internet or maybe that I just don't know the right thing to research but could you please help me? Thanks!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct pile
{
    int donnee;
    struct pile *precedent;
} Pile;

void pile_push(Pile **p_pile, int donnee)
{
        Pile *p_nouveau = malloc(sizeof *p_nouveau);
        if (p_nouveau != NULL)
        {
                p_nouveau->donnee = donnee;
                p_nouveau->precedent = *p_pile;
                *p_pile = p_nouveau;
        }
}

int pile_pop(Pile **p_pile)
{
    int ret = -1;
    if (p_pile != NULL)
    {
        Pile *temporaire = (*p_pile)->precedent;
        ret = (*p_pile)->donnee;
        free(*p_pile), *p_pile = NULL;
        *p_pile = temporaire;
    }
    return ret;
}

void pile_clear(Pile **p_pile)
{
    while (*p_pile != NULL)
    {
        pile_pop(p_pile);
    }
}
```

I tried doing this:

```
int main()
{
    int return_val;
    Pile pile;
    pile_push(Pile, 5);
    return_val = pile_pop(Pile);
    printf(return_val);
}
```

and got this error:

```
expected expression before 'Pile'
too few arguments to function 'pile_push'
```

Comment: what is your precise question mon ami?

Comment: If you don't understand the code how do you know it will even do what you want? Taking random code from the internet that you can't even begin to understand probably isn't a great idea. Better to learn things from first principles. Anyway, "typedef struct for a fifo" doesn't really make much sense. What exactly do you think a "fifo struct" is (it's not clear what your intent is)?

Comment: Try looking up the term 'queue'; that uses a FIFO discipline.  There are also stacks (LIFO or 'last in, first out') and dequeues (double-ended queues) which combine stack and queue functionality.

Comment: I get the overall thing about the code, I just don't know how to initialize my object and use the functions afterwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have mixed up `Pile` and `pile` which is the issue with the first warning. The functions expect a pointer to a pointer to a Pile. That is: They update the value of a pointer, so they need to be passed a reference to a pointer. Your use of printf is also wrong.

```
int main()
{
    int return_val;
    Pile *pile = NULL;
    pile_push(&pile,5);
    return_val = pile_pop(&pile);
    printf("return_val is: %d\n",return_val);
}
```